# image overlay toggle button on screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, overlay

so i have this image code css, it works with some html also. what im trying to do is have an on screen button that toggles this code off or on. this is for my website. i want it default it's off. also, is it possible for the code to remember the users choice? like if the user wanted the overlay on, and then went to the other page, i would like it to remember the choice. sorry for my eng.. im learning.

css

```
    div.nightmode {
      opacity:    0.05; 
      background: url(**image url**);  
      width:      100%;
      height:     100%; 
      z-index:    10;
      top:        0; 
      left:       0; 
      position:   fixed; 
      pointer-events: none;
 }
```

html

```
<body>
  <div class="nightmode"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have couple ways to do it. I think the best one is use cookies.
Here small example:

```
click on DIV to toggle
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sdx2rba9/49/

```
after refresh page cookie set background to previous choice
```

Cannot post in stackoverflow built-in jsfiddle (cookie-secrity).
**REMEMBER:** I am not advanced coder so my code can be not clean or written by long way.